# How can we calculate a processes' contribution to "commit" (/proc/meminfo "Committed_AS")

Tags: memory

We are seeing a "leak" in "commit" over time, and need to track the offending process(es).  RSS ("used" memory") isn't leaking, but the commit is, and its causing the kernel to behave very cruelly (failing to allocate memory when the commit % gets to ~ 200%).  I know we can tune this with /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory but that's not the point - we'd like to find the leaky process.

I've tried various calculations from etc/(proc)/smap and dmap, but nothing adds up across all processes to anything like the commit in /proc/meminfo.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting is sufficiently vague that I'm not clear how to use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is "memory" off topic for a question about linux kernel memory management?

Comment: did you ever make any progress with this? I'm facing the same issue, a few months ago committed memory is continuing to climb at an alarming rate while the rest looks fine or is only growing insignificantly, so far I had no luck in finding out why, looking at rss and vsz didn't help.

Comment: Yes - I ended up writing some shell scripts to gather details and gathered data over several days. The results clearly implicated a specific program. They were quick and dirty, so perhaps not super easy to consume, but if you run them and look at the results it should get you started.  I'll post them in an answer.  I should add this doesn't directly answer the question, but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Posting to provide how we solved this - not elegant or polished, and not a direct answer (we didn't get the actual over commit allocation of a process), but we identified the offender and found a subtle memory leak.

Do apologize for no comments etc, but these were quick one use tools.  With that ...

We looked at `pmap` command results and a scan of `/etc/<pid>/smaps` data for processes, aggregated them for copies of the same process, and loaded them into a spreadsheet for analysis.  We took snapshots several times a day over a week, and looked at the trend in memory usage. This showed us, for an aggregate set of processes with the same name, memory trends over time, which allowed us to identify the offending process set.

The controlling script (ran a group of commands and organized the results in a file)

```
gpmemstatFile=gpmemstat.$(date "+%F.%H.%M.%S.%N" | cut -c 1-23)
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo $(hostname)  >> $gpmemstatFile
echo $(date) >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo >> $gpmemstatFile

echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '/proc/meminfo' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
cat /proc/meminfo >> $gpmemstatFile
echo >> $gpmemstatFile

echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo 'sar -r' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
sar -r >> $gpmemstatFile
echo >> $gpmemstatFile

echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo 'sar -R' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
sar -R >> $gpmemstatFile
echo >> $gpmemstatFile

echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo 'gpsmapstat (/proc/(pid)/smaps aggregates)' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
gpsmapsstat  httpd oninit fglrun java fastcgi gdcproxy >> $gpmemstatFile
echo >> $gpmemstatFile

echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo 'gppmapstat (pmap -d -x aggregates)' >> $gpmemstatFile
echo '-----------------------------------------------------' >> $gpmemstatFile
gppmapstat  httpd oninit fglrun java fastcgi gdcproxy >> $gpmemstatFile

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
   scp $gpmemstatFile $1
fi
```

The script to gather process data via `pmap` for all processes of a specific name (you could use other mechanisms to identify the processes to be analyzed). This summed the aggregate memory usage for all processes of a type.

```
printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n" name PID Total  Resident Dirty Private Shared Unshared
for name in $@  ; do

    unset sumTotalMemory sumResidentMemory sumDirtyMemory sumPrivateMemory sumSharedMemory sumUnsharedMemory 


    for pid in $( ps aux | grep $name | awk  '{print $2}') ; do
        xMemory=$(pmap -x $pid | tail -1)
        totalMemory=$(echo $xMemory | awk '{print $3}')
        if [ -n "$totalMemory" ] ; then sumTotalMemory=$(($sumTotalMemory + $totalMemory)) ; fi
        residentMemory=$(echo $xMemory | awk '{print $4}')
        if [ -n "$residentMemory" ] ; then sumResidentMemory=$(($sumResidentMemory + $residentMemory)) ; fi
        dirtyMemory=$(echo $xMemory | awk '{print $5}')
        if [ -n "$dirtyMemory" ] ; then sumDirtyMemory=$(($sumDirtyMemory + $dirtyMemory)) ; fi

        dMemory=$(pmap -d $pid | tail -1)
        privateMemory=$(echo $dMemory | awk '{print $4}')
        if [ -n "$privateMemory" ] ; then 
            privateMemory=${privateMemory:0:${#privateMemory}-1}
            sumPrivateMemory=$(($sumPrivateMemory + $privateMemory))
        fi
        sharedMemory=$(echo $dMemory | awk '{print $6}')
        unset unsharedMemory
        if [ -n "$sharedMemory" ] ; then 
            sharedMemory=${sharedMemory:0:${#sharedMemory}-1} 
            sumSharedMemory=$(($sumSharedMemory + $sharedMemory ))
            unsharedMemory=$(($totalMemory - $sharedMemory))
            sumUnsharedMemory=$(( $sumUnsharedMemory + $unsharedMemory ))
        fi

        #printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n" $name $pid $totalMemory $residentMemory $dirtyMemory $privateMemory $sharedMemory $unsharedMemory

    done

    if [ -n "$sumTotalMemory" ] ; then
        printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n" $name Total $sumTotalMemory $sumResidentMemory $sumDirtyMemory $sumPrivateMemory $sumSharedMemory $sumUnsharedMemory
        printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n" $name MiB $(($sumTotalMemory/1024)) $(($sumResidentMemory/1024)) $(($sumDirtyMemory/1024)) $(($sumPrivateMemory/1024)) $(($sumSharedMemory/1024)) $(($sumUnsharedMemory/1024))
        printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n" $name GiB $(echo "scale=2; $sumTotalMemory/1024/1024" | bc) $(echo "scale=2; $sumResidentMemory/1024/1024" | bc) $(echo "scale=2; $sumDirtyMemory/1024/1024" | bc)  $(echo "scale=2; $sumPrivateMemory/1024/1024"| bc) $(echo "scale=2; $sumSharedMemory/1024/1024"| bc) $(echo "scale=2; $sumUnsharedMemory/1024/1024"| bc)
    fi
done
```

And the script to look at all `proc/<pid>/smaps` files, and aggregate memory data for all processes of a specific name (again you could use other mechanisms to identify the processes to be analyzed). And again this summed the aggregate memory usage for all processes of a type.

```
printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n" name size rss pss shrdCln shrdDrty prvtCln prvtDrty refrncd swap
for name in $*; do

    unset awkFiles
    for pid in $( ps aux | grep $name | awk  '{print $2}') ; do
        if [ -e /proc/$pid/smaps ] ; then   
            awkFiles=${awkFiles}" /proc/$pid/smaps"
        fi
    done
    if [ -n "$awkFiles" ] ; then
        awk -v name="$name" '{ 
            if ($1 == "Size:" ){
                sizeSum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Rss:" ){
                rssSum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Pss:" ){
                pssSum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Shared_Clean:" ){
                sharedCleanSum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Shared_Dirty:" ){
                sharedDirtySum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Private_Clean:" ){
                privateCleanSum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Private_Dirty:" ){
                privateDirtySum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Referenced:" ){
                referencedSum+=$2
            }
            else if ($1 == "Swap:" ){
                swapSum+=$2
            }
        }  
        END { printf "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n", name, sizeSum, rssSum, pssSum, sharedCleanSum, sharedDirtySum, privateCleanSum, privateDirtySum, referencedSum, swapSum}' $awkFiles
    fi
done
```

Again, not polished, and not the actual answer (I still don't know how to get processes in a sorted list of memory commit charge), but it did the trick here.

Comment: and how did you end up identifying committed memory per process? Which of theses values did you have to sum up?

Comment: As indicated up front, we did not get this actual value (commit charge). I have yet to get this precise information; I believe it's not actually available, and to get it you would have to repeat the calculations the kernel does. However, the memory stats show, by group of processes with the same name, overall memory. This allows you to identify the processes with the largest actual memory, and changes over time - which we used to find a large, growing process. This was the offender.

Comment: eventually I figured out that the values didn't add up and it was actually a kernel memory leak, after a kernel upgrade it stopped entirely. the sympton was that userspace (app) memory calculated via /proc/meminfo did not match the actual sum of all processes memory

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but first I would like to find out actual memory usage along with actual shared memory.Please use the below mentioned python script

```
             https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py
```

Hopefully this will help or first step towards debugging...

Comment: Thanks.  I'm already processing smaps and have an abundance of information about the processes memory usage.  The point  was more specific - no available data in smaps or pmap  tracks precisely to the kernel's calculation of overcommit in /proc/meminfo.

The question asks if there's a clean way to get data on each processes contribution to overcommit, specifically.